# Do I need an "of it" in the following case?

Tags: prepositional-phrases, grammaticality-in-context

> Trust. After her husband's affair, was there any (of it) left?

It sounds okay to me with and without the *of it*. But maybe I'm wrong because I'm not a native English speaker. Why should I include it or why not?

Comment: In my opinion the "of it" seems to me a meaningful. Only "Any" will not convey any meanings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds correct either way, but to me the two variants have *very* slightly different meanings.

Without "of it," the question asks whether there was any trust left in a general, universal sense — though it's obviously meant specifically in the context of the trust between the husband and his wife.

With the "of it," the sentence takes a more specific meaning: the "it" refers to the specific "unit" of trust between the husband and his wife, and retroactively constrains the word "trust" to this unit.

So, I would say that with "of it," the feeling of the sentence is that the wife has lost trust in her husband, but without "of it," the feeling of the sentence is that the wife has lost her feeling of trust more generally; she's now more careful about trusting anybody, because of the traumatic experience of having her trust broken by somebody so close to her.

I don't want to overstate the difference. It's really more of how it affects the mood of the sentence, and I think most casual readers would hardly notice the difference.